# how to set generic list to a pre-existing list of the same type?

Tags: c#

I am using c# and have 4 existing lists, each of a different type (i.e. `List<Doctor>`, `List<Patient>` etc')

I have a generic search method which receives type T and should search using LINQ the appropriate list based on the type T.

I created a `var List<T> listToSearch` and wanted to set it to the appropriate list using if's, but I can't set `listToSearch` to any of them.

Code:

```
// at class level:
    private List<Doctor> doctorList;
    private List<Patient> patientList;
    private List<Visit> visitList;
    private List<Treatment> treatmentList;

    public IEnumerable search<T>(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
    {
        List<T> listToSearch = null;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Doctor)) { listToSearch = doctorList; }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Patient)) { listToSearch = patientList; }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Visit)) { listToSearch = visitList; }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Treatment)) { listToSearch = treatmentList; }


        // more code that isn't relevant to the question here
    }
```

Each `typeof(T)` line brings up an error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<Doctor/Patient/Visit/Treatment>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'`

How do I change this code to allow for the use of Generic lists?

Comment: What are you planning to _do_ with those lists?  If you need to use fields specific to those types it may be better to have 4 `search` methods and make _only the common logic_ generic.

Comment: In my book, having to use `typeof()` in a generic method is a code smell. Time to put the thinking cap on - you probably want a List<T> argument to `search`.

Comment: I want to run a LINQ query on the appropriate list and return it. I am trying to avoid doing 4 different search methods for each type since it will cause of lot of code (the search lines which I didn't post) to be written multiple times. the use of typeof() might not be optimal but for now it doesn't stop my program from running which is my priority at the moment (this is my first c# code ever and I'm still learning)

Comment: "it doesn't stop my program from running" - no, it stops it from _compiling_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it to a `List<T>` by casting it to an object first:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Doctor)) { listToSearch = (List<T>)(object)doctorList; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because *`T` is not known at compile time*.  You are asking to take a list of a known type and use it as a list of an *unknown* type, which is not allowed (without dynamics or some other non-compile-time-type-safe mechanism).

Since you're only supporting 4 types anyways, it sounds like you need four `search` methods that call a generic common method (if appropriate):

```
public IEnumerable<Doctor> searchDoctors(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    List<Doctor> listToSearch = doctorList;
    // more code that isn't relevant to the question here
}

public IEnumerable<Patient> searchPatients(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    List<Patient> listToSearch = patientList;
    // more code that isn't relevant to the question here
}

public IEnumerable<Visit> searchVisits(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    List<Visit> listToSearch = visitList;
    // more code that isn't relevant to the question here
}

public IEnumerable<Treatment> searchTreatments(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    List<Treatment> listToSearch = treatmentList;
    // more code that isn't relevant to the question here
}
```

otherwise you're going to have a lot of code validating/casting/converting types that is susceptible to runtime errors.

**Side note:**

Since you are new to C# - I would recommend not trying to optimize/refactor too much using generics, etc.  Write code that *works* (even if it's using copy-paste, not DRY, etc.), then make it *better*.  Otherwise you spend a *lot* more time trying to shoehorn your program into some pattern that thinking about how the program *should* work.

Comment: this will cause a lot of duplicated code, all of the "more code that isn't relevant" will exist multiple times and every change to it will require multiple changes which is what I'm trying to avoid by having all the code written only once in a single method...

Comment: Without seeing the "more code that isn't relevant" I can't tell how much of it would be duplicated - it's possible that _that code_ can be generic.  Bottom line - you're trying to go from a known type to an unknown type which isn't easily done.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are asking is not possible.

I would recommend to type your `listToSearch` as `IList`. This will keep as much generic as you want. You can access all common list actions and you don't have to rely on generics.

```
IList listToSearch = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something like this before I understood what generics are for. In my case I was trying to reduce the number of methods that were needed to add data to a handler before writing it as an `xml` file which isn't too far from what you are trying to accomplish. I was trying to reduce the number of exposed methods from 8 to 1. I ended up using an interface instead of a generic.

In short, you probably can get your desired functionality by using an `interface` instead of a `generic`. D Stanley is correct. Write code that works, then improve. That way you can try something with the option of eliminating the changes to restore the functionality. Also, Eric Lippert wrote on the subject on Generics (the post is in stack overflow, I just can't find it right now) that if you write a method for using a generic and immediately throw in logic statements to sort out what the object type is, then you are using generics wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you were, at least, returning `IEnumerable<T>` I could understand using the type parameter, but what you are doing here is reinventing method overloading.

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<Doctor> SearchDoctors(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    return Search(doctorList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

public IEnumerable<Patient> SearchPatients(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    return Search(patientList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

public IEnumerable<Visit> SearchVisits(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    return Search(visitList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

public IEnumerable<Treatment> SearchTreatments(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    return Search(treatmentList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

private IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd)
{
    // more code that isn't relevant to the question here
}
```

By the way, are you aware that default argument values are hardcode in the caller after compilation?

Consider changing to this:

```
public IEnumerable<Doctor> SearchDoctors(string field, string rangeStart)
{
    return Search(doctorList, field, rangeStart);
}


public IEnumerable<Doctor> SearchDoctors(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd)
{
    return Search(doctorList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

public IEnumerable<Patient> SearchPatients(string field, string rangeStart)
{
    return Search(patientList, field, rangeStart);
}

public IEnumerable<Patient> SearchPatients(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd)
{
    return Search(patientList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

public IEnumerable<Visit> SearchVisits(string field, string rangeStart)
{
    return Search(visitList, field, rangeStart);
}

public IEnumerable<Visit> SearchVisits(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd)
{
    return Search(visitList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

public IEnumerable<Treatment> SearchTreatments(string field, string rangeStart)
{
    return Search(treatmentList, field, rangeStart);
}

public IEnumerable<Treatment> SearchTreatments(string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd)
{
    return Search(treatmentList, field, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}

private IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string field, string rangeStart, string rangeEnd = null)
{
    // more code that isn't relevant to the question here
}
```